# Find and fill XML nodes from a PHP object

Tags: php, xml, dom, object, nodes

First of all, sorry about my english.

So, I have an XML with a lot of nodes, like:

```
   <first>
      <second>
         <third/>
         <fourth/>
      </second>
      <fifth>
          <sixth>
             <seventh/>
          </sixth>
      </fifth>
    </first>
```

and I have an object, like:
        Object{
          third: "asd",
          fourth: "asdasd",
          seventh: "asdasdasd"
        }

How can I run through all the nodes of the XML, regardless of their parents, and fill every one of them with the values of the existing properties from the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using the [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
<?php
$object = (object) array(
    'third'   => 'asd',
    'fourth'  => 'asdasd',
    'seventh' => 'asdasdasd'
);

$xml = <<<XML
<first>
    <second>
        <third />
        <fourth />
    </second>
    <fifth>
        <sixth>
            <seventh />
        </sixth>
    </fifth>
</first>
XML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
    $node            = $sxe->xpath("//*[./{$key}]");
    $node[0]->{$key} = $value;
}

echo $sxe->asXML();
```

#### Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<first>
    <second>
        <third>asd</third>
        <fourth>asdasd</fourth>
    </second>
    <fifth>
        <sixth>
            <seventh>asdasdasd</seventh>
        </sixth>
    </fifth>
</first>
```

Comment: I've tried to use my own object, is a little different than the example of the 'asdasdasd'.
I've got the error 'Creating default object from empty value' on the line '$node[0]->{$key} = $value;'. Any idea?

Comment: That might happen if there's no node on the XML to match `$key`, which probably means that `$node` isn't a SimpleXMLElement but FALSE. Try to `print_r` the value for `$node` on each iteration to debug it or simply add a condition to verify `!empty($node)` before your run that line.